# File Download, PrimeFaces , Connection closed when I cancel the download dialog

Tags: primefaces, download

I have a download link in my JSF page using primefaces.
When you click it, browser (and not the program) opens a dialog box asking (Open,save,close). I am using eclipse default browser to view my web application.
So if you click Open or Save, file will be downloaded. Everything is fine.
But if you click cancel everything fails. The error I receive below. I have the bean in conversation scope.

```
WARNING: org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
javax.faces.FacesException: org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at org.primefaces.component.filedownload.FileDownloadActionListener.processAction(FileDownloadActionListener.java:81)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:772)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:912)
    at org.primefaces.component.datalist.DataList.broadcast(DataList.java:248)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:775)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1267)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:82)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:312)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:277)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:325)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:226)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:382)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.flushBuffer(Response.java:645)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.flushBuffer(ResponseFacade.java:326)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.responseFlushBuffer(ExternalContextImpl.java:855)
    at org.primefaces.component.filedownload.FileDownloadActionListener.processAction(FileDownloadActionListener.java:76)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:33)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:69)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:40)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:336)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.OutputWriter.flushChannel(OutputWriter.java:106)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.OutputWriter.flushChannel(OutputWriter.java:74)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.SocketChannelOutputBuffer.flushChannel(SocketChannelOutputBuffer.java:321)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.SocketChannelOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(SocketChannelOutputBuffer.java:392)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.SocketChannelOutputBuffer.flush(SocketChannelOutputBuffer.java:370)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.action(ProcessorTask.java:1174)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.Response.action(Response.java:266)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:378)
    ... 45 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there are 2 or more consistent requests to File download.this happens when you submit request for one file download and request same file again before/while server serving you download request.

This happens if you have Download manager application integrated in to your browser like *Internet Download Manager*, which usually do request a file download twice.

Comment: This also happens when you cancel a normal download. Or close the browser in the middle of retrieving a page, css, js or whatever